# AES128 memcry() crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

```
- (NSData *)kd_AES128EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {
    if (key.length == 0) {
        return nil;
    }
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1];

    memset(keyPtr, 0, sizeof(keyPtr));
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];
    int diff = kCCKeySizeAES128 - (dataLength % kCCKeySizeAES128);
    NSUInteger newSize = 0;

    if (diff > 0) {
        newSize = dataLength + diff;
    }

    char dataPtr[newSize];
    memcpy(dataPtr, [self bytes], [self length]); // crash  EXC_BAD_ACCESS

    ...
    free(buffer);
    return nil;
}
```

in this crash:
newSize = 800016
dataSize = 800001

**When i make AES128 encrypt for NSData(800001 bytes), crash in memcry(), `but if
the data is smaller`, it work normal**

Could someone help me?

Comment: This looks like objective-C not C. Please use the correct tag. Also, code debugging questions should include a [mcve].

Comment: 1. What are you trying to accomplish with `diff` and `kCCKeySizeAES128`? 2. if `diff <= 0`  `newSize` is `0` which is not what you want. 3. What does `kCCKeySizeAES128` have to do with the data length? 4. With the missing code `...` it is hard to tell waty all the provided code is for. 5. The variable name `diff` is not very descriptive as to its function.

Answer (score 1):

your `dataPtr` is allocated in the stack which always has a certain limit. If you are dealing with big chunks of memory, then use heap instead:

```
char *dataPtr = (char *)malloc(newSize);
```

and don't forget to free it later

Answer (score 0):

If `diff <= 0`  `newSize` is `0` so no memory will be aqllocated to `dataPtr`: `char dataPtr[newSize];` so the `memcpy` will crash.